# How to download csv file from website with Python?

Tags: python

There is a website, in that website there is a 'download data' button. Once I click this button, a .csv file will be downloaded. How can I write a Python program to do it? Here is the website: https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/hourly_data_e.html?hlyRange=2013-06-11%7C2023-05-13&dlyRange=2013-06-13%7C2023-05-12&mlyRange=%7C&StationID=51459&Prov=ON&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnName&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=2022&EndYear=2023&selRowPerPage=25&Line=3&searchMethod=contains&txtStationName=Toronto&timeframe=1&time=LST&time=LST&Year=2020&Month=5&Day=22#

After doing some research,

I now understand the HTTP have Tree structure and I could use request and Beautifulsoup go go through each layer to find what I need. But I have gone through the entire tree structure and I didn't find where the csv file is stored. Am I in the right direction? Where should I look into to find where the files are stored?

So I ended up pulling the data shown in the webpage (because I can find them in the tree structure). But I want the csv file in the webpage.

I know there are some similar posts but the ones I checked didn't work. Can someone give me some advice on weather what I am trying to do is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your attempt in the form of a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of sharing my code if I realize I been working toward the wrong direction? It will only waste others' time. Or should I just show the effort I have done in research before I ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I look into to find where the files are stored?

If you inspect what happens if you click that button (via chrome's network tab), you can see the request that is generated. Using this information, you can drop BS4 and get the csv data via urllib3 or requests.

In this case, you want to get:

```
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51459&Year=2020&Month=5&Day=22&time=LST&timeframe=1&submit=Download+Data
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/):

```
import requests

query = {'format': 'csv',
         'stationID': '51459',
         'Year': '2020',
         'Month': '5',
         'Day': '22',
         'time': 'LST',
         'timeframe': '1',
         'submit': 'Download Data'}
url = 'https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html'

r = requests.get(url, params=query)

with open('data.csv', 'w') as fp:
    print(r.text, file=fp)
```

Comment: This is a nicer, more complete example of what I was proposing. Please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Don't worry about that @JonSG, it doesn't matter :)